# Is it possible to create one apk for both android phone and tv?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tv

I already have mobile app, and now i want to make another one for TV. How can i do this, having only 1 apk at the end
I tried adding another activity to manifest with `<intent-filter>` Leanback, but it seems when app starts it getting the first activity from manifest.

**EDIT 1**
including my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.tv.foxprimetv"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.faketouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:banner="@drawable/ic_logo_foxprime">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
            android:value="com.app.tv.foxprimetv.util.CastOptionsProvider" />


        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.AuthorizationActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.tvapp.TvActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.activity.NavigationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name=".util.RadioService"/>
        <receiver android:name=".util.MySMSBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out why it wasnt working. Thats all because of emulator. When Im installing apk on phone, or TV it works correctly and device recognizes it correctly? on the phone Im getting phone activities, on TV tv activities.

Just try to install it on real devices!!

Answer (score 1):

It should have a specific category: `android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: can you elaborate this answer please

Comment: So i edited me question (added code from manifest), it still runs only tv activity on both phone and tv.

Comment: @ЮрійЯремчук How do you run it? Android studio may run the same activity, but you should not see TvActivity in your phone launcher at all.

Comment: I tried to run it in emulators(tv and phone) and on the real phone.The result always is the same.